# Retrieving student attendance data from form to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view

I want to retrieve student attendance from razor view to controller. In one row I want to access Radio Button value. And there are many rows. How can I access all rows data at once and send it to the controller?

**My Razor view is:**

```
 <table class="table">
                        <thead class="thead-inverse">
                            <tr>

                                <th>Full Name</th>
                                <th>Roll No</th>
                                <th>Status</th>

                                @*  <th>Status</th>*@
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @using (@Html.BeginForm("Save", "Attendance", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
                            {

                                foreach (var student in Model.Students)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@student.Name</td>
                                        <td>@student.RollNo</td>
                                        <td>

                                            <div data-toggle="buttons">
                                                <label class="btn btn-success active">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="1" autocomplete="off" checked> Present
                                                </label>
                                                <label class="btn btn-danger">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="2" autocomplete="off" checked> Absent
                                                </label>
                                                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="3" autocomplete="off" checked> On Leave
                                                </label>
                                                <label class="btn btn-warning">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="4" autocomplete="off" checked> Short Leave
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                }
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I attached a screen shot of my web page so that you can see what I want to achieve.

[image: My Web Page View]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have maybe tried passing back a FormCollection in the HttpPost. Here is a simple example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(FormCollection form)
    {
        //form variable should contain data from form controls. 
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of students to the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(List<Students> students)
{
    //here you can manipulate that list 
    return View();
}
```

Make sure in the view you pass all students where submitting or create a "Select all" button